# preg_match to show first match in foreach loop

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an array of patterns:

```
$patterns= array(
    '#http://(www\.)?domain-1.com/.*#i',
    '#http://(www\.)?domain-2.com/.*#i',
    ...
);
```

and I have long string that contains multiple text and urls I want to match the first url occurred in the string, I only tried this :

```
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    preg_match($pattern, $the_string, $match);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($match); echo '</pre>';
}
```

It returns empty arrays where there are no match for some patterns and arrays that contains a url but depending on the order of the array `$patterns`,

how can I find any match of these patterns that occurred first.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the URL you are trying to match and an example pattern?  The issue may lie in your regex pattern and not your  PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have three options:

1. match a [general URL pattern](http://rodneyrehm.de/t/url-regex.html#gruber+revised) and then run that URL against the patterns you've got. If none matched, continue with the second result from the general pattern.
2. run all your patterns with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to get the offset the pattern matched at. find the lowest offset, return your result
3. combine your various patterns to a single pattern. Be aware that there are limits to the length of a pattern ([64K in compiled form](http://mushclient.com/pcre/pcre.html#SEC3))

---

Option 2:

```
<?php

$text = "hello world http://www.domain-2.com/foo comes before http://www.domain-1.com/bar";
$patterns= array(
    '#http://(www\.)?domain-1.com/[^\s]*#i',
    '#http://(www\.)?domain-2.com/[^\s]*#i',
);

$match = null;
$offset = null;
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        if ($matches[0][1] < $offset || $offset === null) {
            $offset = $matches[0][1];
            $match = $matches[0][0];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($match);
```

beware that I changed your demo patterns. I replaced `.*` (anything) by `[^\s]*` (everything but space) to prevent the pattern from matching more than it's supposed to

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $the_string, $match)) {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($match); echo '</pre>';
        break;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Then I think you should work with offsets linke this:

```
$matches = array();
foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $the_string, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        $matches[$match[0][1]] = $match[0][0];
    }
}
echo reset($matches);
```

Comment: You typed it faster than I did :)

Comment: I'm not trying to stop after the first match, this will return a match even if it's in the end of the string but it's pattern is in the beginning of the array patterns.

Comment: While this is a viable solution, that `ksort()` is an unnecessary waste of performance…

Comment: @rodneyrehm Thanks removed it. I prefer yours anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way except evaluting all the strings one at a time, and grabbing the earliest:

```
$easliestPos = strlen($the_string) + 1;
$earliestMatch = false;

foreach ($patterns as $pattern) { 
    if (preg_match($pattern, $the_string, $match)) { 
        $myMatch = $match[0];
        $myMatchPos = strpos($myMatch, $the_string);
        if ($myMatchPos < $easliestPos ) {
            $easliestPos = $myMatchPos;
            $earliestMatch = $myMatch ;
        }
    }
 }

 if ($earliestMatch ) {
    echo $earliestMatch;
 }
```